# Camel Dead Letter Channel for all exceptions

Tags: error-handling, exception, apache-camel, dead-letter

Im creating a dead letter channel errorhandler like below

```
errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("direct:myDLC").useOriginalMessage().maximumRedeliveries(1));

from("direct:myDLC")
.bean(MyErrorProcessor.class);
```

The Bean MyErrorProcessor should be able to handle all types of checked and unchecked exceptions like below..

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    Exception e=(Exception)exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Exception.class);
    e.printStackTrace();
    if(e instanceof MyUncheckedException){
        logger.error("MyUncheckedException: "+((MyException) e).getErrorCode()+" : "+((MyException) e).getErrorDesc());
    }else if(e instanceof MyException){
        logger.error("MyException: "+((MyException) e).getErrorCode()+" : "+((MyException) e).getErrorDesc());
    }
}
```

But after exception is handled the original message should be redirected to route's endpoint.. how to continue route once exception handled like this??

Comment: I don't really understand, it should be redirected to route's endpoint? Which endpoint?

from("direct:myDLC")
.bean(MyErrorProcessor.class)
.to(desiredEndpoint); ?

Comment: Sorry i missed the actual route,   from("file:/E:/Target/").routeId("Route1")
  .setHeader("route1Header").constant("changed")
  .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "Route1Logger", "Inside Route 1")
  .throwException(new MyException("E_MYERROR_01"))
  .to("file:/E:/Target/Done");          once the MyException is handled in deadletterchannel, what should be done to continue the above route.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using continued() will work, it will ignore the error and continue to process, so then you would probably want to handle the specific Exception

see http://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html

```
onException(MyException.class)
    .continued(true)
;
```

If you would use .useOriginalMessage() on this exception handling, the original message would be the message that is continued.